# How program AutoHotKey for Alt + Space + N?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

The sequence Alt + Space + N ( press Alt and Space together, then press N ) can easily minimize the current windows. I need to remap it to a useless key in my keyboard, for example, the right Win key or the Menu key next to it.

I tried many combination and they doesn't work.

```
>#Space::Send {Alt}{Space}n
```

This work, but require pressing two key, the right Win key and Space, while I want it to be a one key hotkey.

```
>#::Send {Alt}{Space}n
```

This doesn't work and only pop the start menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>#` is just a modifier. Modifiers must be used in conjunction with other keys. Use the key `RWin` instead.

```
RWin::Send {Alt}{Space}n
```

Comment: This solve the problem. And I found RWin::Send !{Space}n better because it stick the Alt keystroke to the Space keystroke. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, gunbuster, that is correct. Otherwise, `[Alt]` is released before the `[Space]` is pressed.